# How do i use AngularJs with JsBarcode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Well guys, first sorry if this is kinda poor, but this is my first question.

I'm trying to use angular js to generate a barcode using JsBarcode, but when I put the Angular code like {{y.code}}, the JsBarcode doesn't recognize and just shows me an empty space.

$

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="row" ng-repeat="y in teste">
    <div class="col center">
      <svg class="barcode" jsbarcode-format="EAN13" jsbarcode-value="978020137962" jsbarcode-textmargin="0" jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
      <h4>{{y.code}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  \* i thinked in some like this, but doesn't work*\
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in teste">
    <div class="col center">
      <svg class="barcode" jsbarcode-format="EAN13" jsbarcode-value="{{y.code}}" jsbarcode-textmargin="0" jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
      <h4>{{x.code}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
          $scope.teste = [

            {

              "item": "1",
              "code": " 978020137962",

            },
            {

              "item": "2",
              "code": "978020137129 ",

            },
            {

              "item": "3",
              "code": " 978020137923",

            },
          });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: closing square bracket is missing for $scope.teste = [

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XwegrG?editors=1010

Comment: Ops, sorry, plis guys use the codepen from Naga Sai A, i forgot in the snippet

Comment: Thanks Naga Sai A

Comment: But i istill have the issue with the angular vs jsbarcode

Comment: is it working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use `jsbarcode-value="{{x.code.trim()}}"` instead of `{{y.code}}`

**Issue:** 
**y** is undefined in second div, as the ng-repeat div closes before the start of second ng-repeat where is **y** not available and only **x.code** is available

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
          $scope.teste = [

            {

              "item": "1",
              "code": " 978020137962",

            },
            {

              "item": "2",
              "code": "978020137129 ",

            },
            {

              "item": "3",
              "code": " 978020137923",

            },
            ]
          });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="row" ng-repeat="y in teste">
    <div class="col center">
      <svg class="barcode" jsbarcode-format="EAN13" jsbarcode-value="978020137962" jsbarcode-textmargin="0" jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
      <h4>{{y.code}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  \* i thinked in some like this, but doesn't work*\
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in teste">
    <div class="col center">
      <svg class="barcode" jsbarcode-format="EAN13" jsbarcode-value="{{x.code.trim()}}" jsbarcode-textmargin="0" jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
      <h4>x-{{x.code}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XwegrG